# Glassfish 3.1.1: Retrieve HTTP-Authentication in RESTful Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I´m using HTTP-Authentication based on my customer-table. After the user is authenticated a restful webservice is called. But how can I access in the webservice the HTTP-Authentication (the Header Data of the HttpRequest)?
My code looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}") 
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public ObjectList read(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
... //how to get here the HTTP-Username and Password?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the `Principal` and its role, inject @Context `SecurityContext` in the class body or in the method input parameters.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core;
//
public ObjectList read(
    @PathParam("id") Integer id,
    @Context SecurityContext sc) {
    String principalUserName = sc.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    if (sc.isUserInRole("MyRole")) {
        return new MyRoleResource();
    } else {
        return new MyDefaultRoleResource();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more parameters to your method like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;

// ...

public ObjectList read(
    @PathParam("id") Integer id,
    @HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent,
    @HeaderParam("X-auth-token") String authToken) ...
```