# How should I make REST sub-resources that are sometimes read-only accessible?

Tags: rest

I have a user:

```
GET /user/1 -> {id:1,name:"john"}
```

My authorization engine makes sure that anyone can `GET /user/1`, but `PUT /user/1` or `PATCH /user/1` is restricted to john himself or a system admin.

How do I handle parts of the user that can only be modified by an admin? For example, what if I have a property `blocked`, which determines if the user is allowed to log in? For obvious reasons, john should not be able to change his blocked status, only an admin should.

I see two ways to do this:

1. Make permissions a completely separate resource, accessible either at `/permissions/:user` or `/user/:user/permissions`, and allow only admins to access that path. Thus `PUT` and `PATCH` to `/user/:user` can change the user all it wants, it really only modifies user-modifiable data, while `/permissions` is admin-modifiable data
2. Make permissions built into the user-object, but do logic within the `PUT` or `PATCH` handler to prevent anyone other than admin from modifying it.

Option 2 keeps the user object intact, while option 1 allows me to completely encapsulate and separate data the user or an admin can change from data only an admin can change.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. Are you looking for authentication? Usually if a user tries to access a resource they’re not allowed to view/modify, you’d send either a **401 Unauthorized** or **403 Forbidden** HTTP status code.

Comment: Nope, not looking for auth/auth. I have a pretty decent engine in place. I am trying to design the architecture and hence the REST paths around it. When a user accesses a path for which they are denied access, they should get a *403*.

Comment: Your paths wouldn’t change; that’s against REST principles. If a user needs to authenticate to view a resource send a 401 status code. If the user has authenticated but still isn’t permitted to view the resource, send a 403 status code.

Comment: @deitch: this is your choice. I personally prefer second option. If you are using Container Managed Authentication, this is very easy to handle and to maintain. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9005331/870122) on the subject

Comment: @perissf, so you prefer to have a single user object, especially since it is mapped one-to-one anyways? I guess the only reason I am really bothered by it, is that having separate resources (or sub-resources) makes it really easy to manage the authorization all the way up and down.

Comment: @MartinBean, how would either of these options be against REST principles? Nothing in Fielding's work suggests that having sub resources, or resources accessed from different paths, is wrong.

Comment: @deitch I mean, after you have identified the user role, you either accept the proposed changes / edits to the object, or send the HTTP error codes as suggested in the first comment

Comment: @perissf so you like a single path `PUT /user/:user` and a single object, and add the business logic to filter out various requests based on user role, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @deitch: correct. Be welcome

Comment: So part of my reason for asking wasn't purity of RESTfulness. There are enough frameworks out there in various langs (and I wrote one myself for node http://github.com/deitch/booster) that provide automatic REST routing. It is easier to stick authorization on the front-end via another filter/handler/middleware, and even examine query parameters. But when you start considering parts of the body, you start needing to do more custom stuff.

Comment: And to make it more complex: what if the existing record has `{blocked:true}`, and a user tries to `PUT` an update that has the same data, except no `blocked` field?

Comment: The logic as to what a user can and cannot edit can become complicated, I was wondering if it made sense to just have user-related resources that are separate resources, and editable only by admins (or certain roles)?

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in
> the    way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the
> resource    identified by the Request-URI.  In a PUT request, the
> enclosed entity    is considered to be a modified version of the
> resource stored on the    origin server, and the client is requesting
> that the stored version    be replaced.  With PATCH, however, the
> enclosed entity contains a set    of instructions describing how a
> resource currently residing on the    origin server should be modified
> to produce a new version.  The PATCH    method affects the resource
> identified by the Request-URI, and it    also MAY have side effects on
> other resources; i.e., new resources    may be created, or existing
> ones modified, by the application of a    PATCH.

According to the [PATCH method definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).

I did not find anything about how to define full and partial terms, so it is probably up to you. So in the actual auth context the full can mean everything the current user has access to, and the partial can mean less than full.

So there is nothing wrong if you don't send the permissions in a PUT when your user cannot modify the permissions, just an admin.

So permissions can be a both a sub-resource and a separate resource or even part of a separate security service.